# Using the MAX aggregation window function correctly in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a log table which records the run history of various background jobs.

Now I need to display the most recent run of each and every job along with some data.

Here is my solution:

```
SELECT BackgroundJobId, bjl.LogId, ExecStartTime, ExecEndTime, ErrorDescription, Debug
FROM BackgroundJobLog bjl
JOIN (
    SELECT LogId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BackgroundJobId ORDER BY ExecStartTime DESC) rowNumber
    FROM BackgroundJobLog
    WHERE BackgroundJobStatusId IN (1, 3)
) AS bjl2 ON bjl.LogId = bjl2.LogId AND bjl2.rowNumber = 1
```

It returns 157 rows as expected, each row containing a distinct `BackgroundJobId` with the information from the most recent run of that job.

However, the performance is a problem. Right now, that log table has about 25,000,000 rows satisfying the nested `SELECT` statement. It seems to be a terrible waste to join with 25,000,000 rows when all I need is the row with the most recent `ExecStartTime`.

So, I figured I could use the `MAX` aggregation window function. But for the life of me I do not understand how. The following statement:

```
SELECT BackgroundJobId, LogId, MAX(ExecStartTime) OVER (PARTITION BY BackgroundJobId) ExecStartTime
FROM BackgroundJobLog
WHERE BackgroundJobStatusId IN (1, 3)
```

attempts to return the same 25,000,000 rows. True, for the same `BackgroundJobId` the most recent `ExecStartTime` value is returned, but it is repeated as many times as there are rows with the same `BackgroundJobId` ! Of course, each row has its own `LogId`. Whereas I want just the row with the most recent ExecStartTime within the same `BackgroundJobId`.

How can I do it efficiently?

**EDIT**

Guys, nested select is a nested select. Little difference whether it is joined explicitly or selected from as a CTE or directly. As long as there is nested select the performance is abismal.

**EDIT 2**

There is an index on the `BackgroundJobStatusId`:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_BackgroundJobLog_BackgroundJobStatusId ON [BackgroundJobLog] ([BackgroundJobStatusId]) INCLUDE ([LogId],[BackgroundJobId],[ExecStartTime])
```

**EDIT 3**

The schema of the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE BackgroundJobLog
(
    LogId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    BackgroundJobId int NOT NULL,
    ExecStartTime datetime NULL,
    ExecEndTime datetime NULL,
    ErrorDescription ntext NULL,
    BackgroundJobStatusId int NOT NULL,
    Debug ntext NULL,
    LogEntryId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_LogEntryId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (LogEntryId),
    CONSTRAINT IX_BackgroundJobLog UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (LogId)
)
```

**EDIT 4**

Please, find below the execution plan for the Hamlet Hakobyan's answer:
[image]

**EDIT 5**

Please, find below the execution plan for the Kirill Zorin's answer:
[image]

Comment: *As long as there is nested select the performance is abismal.* Could you please back it up somehow?

Comment: The nested select returns over 25,000,000 rows, whereas only 157 are actually needed. Isn't it enough? But I also tried the other approaches. As long as a nested select returns that many rows - no improvement.

Comment: no, it's not enough. The nested select does not "return" anything, the db optimizer is more complex than that. Have you tried creating the index I suggested? Without this index, the server will have to process all 25M records no matter what.

Comment: Any answer you get here is going to require a sort due to the nature of the data you want out of the kind of data you have. As such, a covering index like Quassnoi suggested would help your speed immensely. The performance is not based on a simple "inner/outer" select statement ordering.

Comment: There is an index named `IX_BackgroundJobLog_BackgroundJobStatusId` - please see the **EDIT 2**. Is it the index you are referring to?

Comment: @mark: no, I'm referring to an index on `BackgroundJobLog (BackgroundJobId, ExecStartTime) INCLUDE (BackgroundJobStatusId)`. You see, SQL Server has to understand which of your 25M records holds the largest start time, job-wise. Unless you have such an index, it has no other option as to page through all the records and just find the largest one.

Comment: @Quassnoi - Would you mind providing a formal reply to my question? Along with your version of the query and index? I would like to credit you, if your answer is the right one.

Comment: Which question exactly? *How can I do it efficiently?* Just create the index (which is crucial for performance) and do any of the three queries in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24417922/55159). `MAX` won't help you improve performance, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Well, I did create the index. And then I ran the query of Jaaz Cole.  But guess what? Sql Server did not use it! It insists on using the other index - `IX_BackgroundJobLog_BackgroundJobStatusId`. Got exactly the same execution plan as for the Hamlet Hakobyan's query - see **EDIT 4**. I will try to force the SQL server to use your index and see what happens.

Comment: @mark: do you have a separate table with jobs? If you don't, can you create the indexed view I suggested in the second query? If you have or can create neither, then use the CTE (I've just updated it). The index won't be used for Jaaz Cole's query, it will only be used for mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query to work fast, you need two things:

- A list of distinct `BackgroundJobId`
- A composite index on `BackgroundJobLog (BackgroundJobId, ExecStartTime) INCLUDE (BackgroundJobStatusId)`

If you have a separate table with jobs, just use it:

```
SELECT  bl.*
FROM    job
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                *
        FROM    BackgroundJobLog
        WHERE   BackgroundJobId = job.id
                AND BackgroundJobStatusId IN (1, 3)
        ORDER BY
                ExecStartTime DESC
        ) bl
```

If you don't, you can create an indexed view to get such a list:

```
CREATE VIEW job
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT  backgroundJobId, COUNT_BIG(*) cnt
FROM    BackgroundJobLog
GROUP BY
        backgroundJobId
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX
        ux_job
ON      job (backgroundJobId)
GO
```

then repeat the previous query, adding `NOEXPAND`:

```
SELECT  bl.*
FROM    job WITH (NOEXPAND)
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                *
        FROM    BackgroundJobLog
        WHERE   BackgroundJobId = job.id
                AND BackgroundJobStatusId IN (1, 3)
        ORDER BY
                ExecStartTime DESC
        ) bl
```

Alternatively, you might build such a list in a CTE:

```
WITH    job (id) AS
        (
        SELECT  MIN(BackgroundJobId)
        FROM    BackgroundJobLog
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  (
                SELECT  backgroundJobId
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  backgroundJobId,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY backgroundJobId) rn
                        FROM    BackgroundJobLog bl
                        WHERE   bl.backgroundJobId > job.id
                        ) q
                WHERE   rn = 1
                )
        FROM    job
        WHERE   id IS NOT NULL
        )
SELECT  bl.*
FROM    job
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                *
        FROM    BackgroundJobLog
        WHERE   BackgroundJobId = job.id
                AND BackgroundJobStatusId IN (1, 3)
        ORDER BY
                ExecStartTime DESC
        ) bl
WHERE   job.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I'm looking to expand my knowledge here, so this is more a question of why or why not, but..would the composite index, for this particular query, not be better if ExecStartTime was in descending order?

Comment: @JaazCole: SQL Server is able to scan indexes in either direction.

Comment: My page was not refreshed, did not see your answer. I do have a separate table of job definitions, very small, naturally. Let me try your suggestion again.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see that the JOIN is necessary.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BackgroundJobId ORDER BY ExecStartTime DESC) rn
    FROM BackgroundJobLog
    WHERE BackgroundJobStatusId IN (1, 3)
)
SELECT BackgroundJobId
      , LogId
      , ExecStartTime
      , ExecEndTime
      , ErrorDescription
      , Debug
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Didn't you see any difference? You haven't got the self-join here.

Comment: Yes, I ran it. No improvement. And it is understandable - the CTE returns 25,000,000 rows.

Comment: What is selectivity of `BackgroundJobStatusId`? Have you index on it? Same for `BackgroundJobId` and `ExecStartTime`.

Comment: Yes, there is an index on it - see **EDIT 2**. But 99% of the table satisfies the condition of status 1 or 3.

Comment: Can you show the execution plan? What about the BackgroundJobId and ExecStartTime?

Comment: See **EDIT 4** for the execution plan.

Comment: Try to add an index on `ExecStartTime`.

Answer (score 0):

It strikes me that you should be able to eschew the join entirely, by selecting everything you want in the inner query, plus the rownumber, selecting everything but the rownumber in the outer query, and change the where clause to contain only the rownumber. So, does the execution plan of this look any better?

```
SELECT BackgroundJobId, LogId, ExecStartTime, ExecEndTime, ErrorDescription, Debug
FROM (
    SELECT BackgroundJobId, LogId, ExecStartTime, ExecEndTime, ErrorDescription, Debug
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BackgroundJobId ORDER BY ExecStartTime DESC) rowNumber
    FROM BackgroundJobLog
    WHERE BackgroundJobStatusId IN (1, 3)
    ) bjl
WHERE rowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use MAX() you can try this:

```
SELECT BackgroundJobId, LogId
FROM
(
SELECT BackgroundJobId, LogId, ExecStartTime, MAX(ExecStartTime) OVER (PARTITION BY BackgroundJobId) MaxExecStartTime
FROM BackgroundJobLog
WHERE BackgroundJobStatusId IN (1, 3)
)
WHERE ExecStartTime = MaxExecStartTime
```

Comment: Please see the **EDIT 5** for the execution plan. Abismal.